# ISA as reverse proxy for multiple SharePoint servers

Tags: sharepoint, isa-server

I am trying to setup ISA to act as a reverse proxy for multiple SharePoint servers - the redirection to the correct server should be done by a predefined url fragment as follows:

- `http://externalurl/sites/Server1`/... -> goes to SharePoint server 1
- `http://externalurl/sites/Server2/`... -> goes to SharePoint server 2

There is also a SharePoint mapped to the root of the ISA, which responds directly to `http://externalurl/`

The problem is that the Server 1 and Server 2 SharePoint servers are trying to retrieve images, stylesheets and javascripts sometimes from the /_layouts folder which is mapped on the root, and therefore ISA will redirect the request to the root SharePoint server.

How can I avoid this situation? Is there perhaps a means to configure ISA to redirect based on a client session rather than individual http requests?

Comment: ISA server? You realise that the newest version of that is about 9 years old and rather unsupported right? While ISA 2006 and Sharepoint 2010 is a supported scenario (http://www.benjaminathawes.com/2010/08/22/publishing-sharepoint-2010-with-isa-server-2006-sp1/) I really think you'll struggle to find good help with this and should be looking to upgrade ISA to Forefront (also doomed, but supported a bit longer at least) or find a new site publishing method entirely (celestix?)

Comment: Unfortunately, upgrading from ISA is not an option for us at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have a hard time with that one.  For one SharePoint doesn't like re-written URL's all that much (and that's why MS doesn't support it).  You can re-write the server portion, but not the content links.

If you have different SharePoint farms they should have different URLs.  SharePoint makes use of a lot of relative links and client side and server redirects that make it unpleasant if even possible to manage in this fashion.